# Effective way to get urls of files and folders

Tags: c#

Let's say that I can get certain txt files from a website via a url that looks something like something.com/folderIndex/folderIndex_fileIndex.txt and I don't know the exact number of files, but I want to get the URLs of all the files in all the folders. What would be the optimal way to do this ? Currently I am doing the following.

```
public async void GetValidFolderCount()
        {
            bool valid = true;
            int folderIndex = 0;
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                while (valid)
                {
                    folderIndex++;
                    string url = String.Format("{0}/{1}", rootUrl, folderIndex);
                    var result = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url));
                    if (result.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        valid = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    FolderCount++;
                    bool res =  await GetValidFileCount(folderIndex, url);
                }
            }
            GetComplete = true;
        }
```

btw, I had to use `Task<bool>` here because without it the number of url's would be different every time.

```
public async Task<bool> GetValidFileCount(int folderIndex, string baseUrl)
    {
        bool valid = true;
        int fileIndex = 0;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            while (valid)
            {
                fileIndex++;
                string fileName = folderIndex + "_" + ((fileIndex < 10) ? ("0" + fileIndex) : fileIndex.ToString()) + fileExtension;
                string fileAddress = String.Format("{0}/{1}", baseUrl,fileName);
                try
                {
                    var result = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(fileAddress));
                    if (result.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        valid = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    continue;
                }
                UrlRepository.UrlList.Add(fileAddress);
            }
        }
        return true;

    }
```

This approach takes up to 2 minutes,  I am pretty sure it could not be considered effective, however the overall number of items in the end is about 1900, so I am not really sure.

I also considered the following approach : parse the HTML and find the anchors, but it did not seem like a good idea.

UPD: The overall goal is to download all the files, but I have to implement a progress bar that would show the number of files I downloaded and number of files left ,so I thought that getting the url's beforehand is a good idea as I get the number of files and I got the url's.

Comment: `catch { continue; }` — huh, deal with this pokémon exception handling *first*.

Comment: @Nicolas please don't use `inline code` to highlight random terms (txt, URL, parse, HTML). It's for inline code.

Comment: Yeah, the catch {continue; } thing is not very good , I had to put the try catch there in the first place because the website sometimes is down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP has no "list files" command, so you're down to two options if you want to discover files that are present in a directory (given the server actually serves files from that directory):

1. Try to download all files that you know or can predict the name of.
2. Parse the server-generated index document.

The latter option is more feasible.

Of course you could do the former smarter, granted the files are numbered predictably and contiguously. You could perform a binary search of some sort.

It all depends on your actual goal though, which you did not explain. Given the information in the question, I'd just parse the HTML of the index document.

Comment: Okay I will add the overall goal in the question. Basically after I have gotten the urls I will download all the files, but I have to find out the exact number of files because I will need to have a progress bar which indicates how many files I have downloaded and how many are left.